# How to adjust for the blue navigation/"using your location" banner?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uikit

I haven't been able to find any documentation about the iOS 8 blue location banner, and when it appears, it pushes my whole app window down.  I'd like to be able to adjust for it (and resize my views) if the blue banner is present.  I don't even know what the official name of the banner is!  Anybody have any luck?

Comment: If you use Auto-Layout, your views will automatically resize when the banner (and hence the Top Layout Guide) grows in size.